# Access Azure RateCardAPI using ADAL without login prompt

Tags: azure, adal, ratecard-api

We need to build a simple windows service to fetch the data from Azure Rate Card API and store the data in local database. To do so, i started to follow [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-ratecard-api/) however, it prompts for user credentials to AcquireToken for subsequent calls. providing this capability inside a windows service, it would be ideal if we could just configure a username / pwd to fetch the data from rate card API.

I have tried to look around quite a bit but have not found a way to AcquireToken without the prompt. Is there a way to achieve the desired objective ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally found the solution for this. It basically guides you through the process of providing user credentials within the code to acquire the token and then make the API calls accordingly.

This [article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) and the related [source code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless)